# Probability of no two equal adjacent numbers

Tags: probability, combinatorics

We create a number with $N$ digits. Every digit is between $0$ to $9$, and can show up anywhere in the number, and without any limit of how many times.

What is the probability such that there are no two adjacent numbers that are equal?

I think:
First we choose any number, and then we can choose $(10-1)$ of the numbers. 
My first guess was:

$P(A)=\frac{10\cdot9^{N-1}}{10^N}$

Why I'm bothered by this question:

If we choose one number at a time (from the left), I just have to choose a number that is just not the previous one. For example, If $N=3$
So If I choose from the left, I will have $10\cdot 9\cdot 9$, But If choose the rightmost, and the leftmost first - $10\cdot 8\cdot 10$ . But $10\cdot 9\cdot 9 \ne 10\cdot 8\cdot 10$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach is correct.

Concerning what's bothering:

If by $N=3$ you choose left utmost and right utmost equal then there are $9$ possibilities for the middle.

So you have: $$10\times 8\times 9+10\times 9\times1$$
possibilities.

This equals $10\times 9\times9$.